# What made Messenger's orbit to decrease?

Tags: messenger

Why Messenger spacecraft fell upon Mercury? What made its orbit to decrease so to lead to the impact?

UPDATE. Seems a duplicate.

Comment: @briligg You are totally wrong. The Messenger crashed only when it spent all its fuel to prolong its life. Iven the pressurizer gas was used to rise its orbit. Please research yourself before commenting and downvoting!

Comment: @briligg so why it crashed, what made its orbit to decrease? From your own link: "After running out of fuel, and with no way to increase its altitude, MESSENGER was finally unable to resist the sun’s gravitational pull on its orbit." What exactly is this "Sun's gravitational pull"?

Comment: Mmm, the phrasing left it open to interpretation. Alright, i'll delete my comments. If an edit is made to the post i can undo my downvote, i believe. Check out Russell's linked question.

Comment: @Russell Borogove indeed, seems a duplicate. I've marked it as such.

Comment: Anixx - make any kind of edit on the question and i can undo the downvote.

Comment: @briligg done..